# atd, batch // Setting the load limiting factor

Tags: at, load, batch-jobs

I am launching non interactive jobs using `batch`, and I would like to increase the load limiting factor in order to use all 8 of my cores. I am on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

From what I understand, `batch` uses `atd` to do the jobs. Jobs start when the load factor goes under a threshold, called the *load limiting factor*. It is said in the `man` of `atd` that we can change this factor using the `-l` option.

My question: how can I use this `atd -l XX` option? When I type, for instance, `atd -l 7.2` before `batch`, it doesn't seem to be changing anything.

What I have found so far:

- In this question [How to run bash script via multithreading](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/292555/how-to-run-bash-script-via-multithreading/292598#292598), one contributor proposes to do this in the '`atd` service starting script'. I guess that it refers to the `/etc/init.d/atd`, but I do not know what to change there, cf next bullet point.
- I have found pages, such as this one http://searchitchannel.techtarget.com/feature/Understanding-run-level-scripts-in-Fedora-11-and-RHEL, where they propose to: "modify the following line (in the start section) of the `/etc/init.d/atd` script: `daemon /usr/sbin/atd`. Replace it with this line, using the `-l` argument to specify the new minimum system load value: `daemon /usr/sbin/atd -l 1.6`". However, there is no such a line in `/etc/init.d/atd`.

It seems that it can be introduced in the `/etc/init.d/atd`, but I do not know where. I have never changed such files.

So, how can I change the load limiting factor used by the `batch` command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution:

- Create a file: `/etc/init/atd.override`
- Add a line `exec atd -l 7.2`
- Then `sudo service atd restart`

It has to do with how the 'Upstart init daemon' works. Explanations there: http://linux.die.net/man/5/init
If the file `/etc/init/atd.override` already exists with an line starting with `exec`, edit this line.

Comment: I was put on the right track by this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13553623/where-should-i-add-the-rest-option-for-mongodb/13554220

Comment: Also works in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Comment: See also https://askubuntu.com/questions/923975/how-to-pass-command-line-arguments-to-atd-init-script-in-ubuntu-16-04

Answer (score 2):

Edit `/lib/systemd/system/atd.service` on Ubuntu 16.04 / systemd.

After appending `-l «load avg»` to the `ExecStart`:

```bsh
$ cat /lib/systemd/system/atd.service 
[Unit]
Description=Deferred execution scheduler
Documentation=man:atd(8)

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/atd -f -l 7.2
IgnoreSIGPIPE=false

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.targe
```

you'll see a message when running `systemctl status atd` or (`service atd status`):

> Warning: atd.service changed on disk. Run 'systemctl daemon-reload' to reload units.

Running that command gets rid of the warning, but to actually pick up the change the service needs to be restarted by `systemctl restart atd` (`service atd restart)`.

Comment: Nice answer! One point though: instead of editing units in /lib/systemd..., it's recommended to copy the files over to /etc/systemd/... and edit the copy (the unit in /etc/systemd will override the unit in /lib/systemd).

Comment: @lgeorget I have added an [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/692354/) which uses `systemctl edit` to override `ExecStart` into `/etc/systemd/`. It builds upon this answer.

Answer (score 2):

This builds upon the [answer by Wesley B.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/363565/). It applies if using `systemctl`. Instead of updating the service configuration directly, an [**override**](https://askubuntu.com/a/659268/) can be defined for it. It is better to do it this way because the OS can otherwise replace the service configuration at any time. This answer was tested with Ubuntu 21.10.

1. Run `sudo systemctl edit atd` and insert:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/atd -f -l 3.0 -b 5
```

Above, the line which is just `ExecStart=` with no value is necessary to nullify the old value. In the next line, set the values of `-l` and `-b` as required, referring to its [man](https://linux.die.net/man/8/atd) page.

This writes the above lines to `/etc/systemd/system/atd.service.d/override.conf`. If this file is added without `systemctl edit`, then `sudo systemctl daemon-reload` may have to be run.

2. Run `sudo systemctl restart atd`.
3. Verify the status:

```
systemctl status atd
ps aux | grep [a]td
```

These should show the service and process status, both with the customized args.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Ubuntu 16.04 LTS nearby, but on Debian-based system  `/etc/init.d/atd` will usually say something like:

```
case "$1" in
  start)
        log_daemon_msg "Starting deferred execution scheduler" "atd"
        start_daemon -p $PIDFILE $DAEMON -l 7
        log_end_msg $?
```

note where I added `-l 7` part. Then you need to restart with `/etc/init.d/atd restart`, and check with `ps auxwww|grep atd` if it was accepted.

note that sometimes you'll have `/etc/default/atd` which is the easier way (and better, as your changes won't be silently wiped on next upgrade)

Comment: The file `/etc/init.d/atd` does not have something like that. Your answer helps me realize that editing this file was not the solution for Ubuntu, at least from version 12.04 LTS. I finally found a solution, cf the answer.